# IE8 Flash arrow keys scroll screen. How to fix it?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8

I've a flash games site, and Im having a lot of difficulties to make it show in internet explorer 8.

When you are playing any flash, the arrow keys that should belong to the flash scroll the page up and down (probably left and right too). This was happening in both ie7 and ie8.
I placed the flash inside an iframe, that fixed to IE7, but the problem persists on IE8.

If I change the flash wmode from transparent to window, the page stops scrolling, but this breaks all my menus and banners, that get hidden behind the flash when they expand.

How can I place a flash, with wmode transparent, and make arrow keys work in the expeted way in IE8? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it worked out on iframes after changing the DOCTYPE to frameset.

I have no idea why transitional didnt worked out... ie is ie...

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I'm trying everything with the iframe&DOCTYPE combination and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IE8 bug that will not allow you to utilize the arrow keys.  The only way to fix this issue is to set the wmode to window.  I know this is not what you are asking, but this is the only fix for the issue.