# Prevent scrolling in IE when flash has focus

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a web page where users can play flash games. We are now making some changes to the page which requires the games to be embedded with `wmode=transparent` or `wmode=opaque` so that we can show HTML elements on-top of the flash games. The problem is that in Internet Explorer (on all versions) the whole page scrolls if a user presses the up/down arrow keys. I've tried everything I can think of and I've spent a whole day searching for a solution without success.

So far I've tried putting the game inside a iframe and I tried disabling the up/down keys with JS, none of which solves my problem.

The requirements are: wmode has to be `transparent` or `opaque` and I **can't** modify the flash games.

Comment: I hope you are not putting in `wmode=transparent|opaque` into your code. It should be `wmode="transparent"` or `wmode="opaque"` surely?! The bar (`|`) means you select either `transparent` or `opaque`.

Comment: Off course ... one or the other not both.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the event on the container `div` element, just for chuckles? If you can capture the event on the containing DOM element, you can just cancel propagating the event there.

Comment: @Krof Drakula I've tried to capture it on the `body` without success. Can you show me some code just in case I'm doing something wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is simply no way around this. We will just have to accept the fact that HTML stuff (FB like chat in our case) will hide behind flash games.

But I still hope somebody proves me wrong :)

Comment: The correct answer is, you should treat Flash instances on the page as a technical limitation and design the page around it as such. ;)

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes that just ain't possible :\

Comment: It's always possible, unless it's a specific requirement by the client. It's all about educating the client — they're used to the fact that not all browser can do everything, this is just one more bullet point.

Comment: This is not for a client, it's for my job and we have accepted the fact that thing's won't work properly in IE :)

Comment: For all intents and purposes, in your case, you yourselves are your own client. Not a pun, just an observation and fact.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent scrolling when using `wmode=transparent` in Flash is to prevent scrolling using the arrow keys for the whole page. [This page](https://www.mochimedia.com/community/forum/topic/best-way-to-prevent-page-scroll-when-using-arrow-keys) summarizes it best.

Basically, when `transparent` mode is active, the keyboard events in IE are propagated through to the browser; I don't know how to prevent scrolling (haven't tested), but you'd basically have to prevent keyboard scrolling globally.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374513/ie8-flash-arrow-keys-scroll-screen-how-to-fix-it) highlights a possible workaround for IE8, and an example of the implementation using jQuery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446069/disable-scrolling-with-arrow-keys-in-flash). I don't have a copy of IE on me right now, but it might be worth a try.

AFAIK, though, games in Flash usually don't work very well with `wmode=transparent`, since focus can be stolen without user interaction. Your best bet would be reworking the page so as not to require Flash to have HTML overlays (even YouTube avoids having `transparent` set on their page, and they own the whole content).

Comment: Unfortunately not having HTML overlays is not an option. I'll have a look at your links, cheers!

Comment: Heh, I've already seen all those links :) Maybe I have to go trough them again :)

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to focus the flash movie first before any key actions are intercepted. This is actually a good behaviour, and shouldn’t be changed.

It would be a good idea to somehow ask the user to focus the movie voluntarily, maybe by putting a bit start button on it which they need to click first. Then all key actions should be sent to Flash.

Comment: Flash gets the focus, as most games have a "click here to start" button (like you said). So that's not an issue. The issue is that key presses are somehow "leaked" to the browser even though flash has focus ...

Answer (score 0):

How about some JS magic, if it works.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Register a KeyPress event handler on the object/embed tags. Let's say you have flash object with id #flashobj

$('#flashobj').keypress( function(event) { event.preventDefault(); } );

Or, more tricky, if the binding on flash object/embed wouldn't work, you can bind the keypress on the whole window, and check something along the lines of:

if (event.target.tagName.toLower() == "object") ...

Mileage may vary, as I remember it event.target is not very reliable...

Hopefully, flash will catch the keyboard event, and the page will ignore it. I know you said you tried it, but your approach might have been different (I suggested two distinctly different ways to do it, one might work)